# Oracle SQL query to find difference in same column

Tags: oracle

I want to find difference between amount based on 'CR' credit or 'DB' debit for same decode .
For Example

```
Sum(Amount)        Decode              CR_OR_DB
-----------------------------------------------
5.84               D000006947               DB
380.12             D000000360               CR      
0.36               D000000546               CR
3.6                D000000010               CR
19.8               D000000013               CR
234.08             D000006947               CR
10.13              D000000360               DB
```

For above table:
I want to subtract debited amount(DB) with credited amount(CR) for same decode.

Comment: These should credits should have been stored as negative numbers. You will need to do an IF THEN statement in your SQL....

Comment: What is your expected output for the above sample data? Please update your question to include the output you're wanting.

Comment: For eg Decode : D000006947 . I wanted  234.08-5.85=228.23

Comment: Also, is this a mysql database or an oracle database? Your tags are misleading.

Comment: Oracle  output shoud be: D000006947    228.23

Comment: This oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use self joints:

```
select t1.decode,(t1.sum-t2.sum) as result from test1 t1,test1 t2 
where t1.decode=t2.decode and t1.cr_or_db='cr' and t2.cr_or_db='db'
```

SQLfiddle : [Output :Check out here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be5f5/22)

Answer (score 1):

Using the table structure above with columns AMOUNT, DECODE and CR_OR_DB use simple teh SUM function and decode the CR/DB to the required sign.

```
select decode, sum (decode(CR_OR_DB,'CR',1,'DB',-1) * amount) amount from test group by decode
```